# Troubleshooting server error after deploying express routes on AWS API Gateway

Tags: express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have this built an api *foo.amazonaws.com/dev/user* using express js that I put on aws lambda. I am using aws api gateway to host the api, and so far it has been working so many time.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import serverless from 'serverless-http';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/user', userRoute);
export const handler = serverless(app);
```

Until today, when I wanted to deploy new api, I noticed slightly changes in the API Gateway interface and steps. I set up proxy resource as usual, so that I could use routes I set up in express js app. But once I deployed and tested on postman, it returns

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I noticed that my previous api has been working fine except for this one I recently uploaded. Any Idea how to fix this? thank you.